# i have to classify an sms into categories like educational, bank related,etc. Is this a problem of topic modelling or text classification?

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, topic-model

If this is a problem of text classification, is a similar dataset available or i have to make one on my own??
I have a dataset of emails for classification into spam/ham.

Answer (score 1):

Topic modeling is usually used in the context of unsupervised learning, while classification is used for supervised learning. So it more depends on your dataset, does it have labels that you can learn from (classification) or does it need to figure out topics itself (topic modeling)?